# Create Custom Index Id Based on Duplicate Rows in Azure Data Flows

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, google-cloud-dataflow

I have a dataset of time punches of an employee like below. I would like to create an Id field with some index that is ordered based on the start time like below so that the punch with the earliest start time begins at 1 and so forth in order (e.g., 1,2,3). In addition, the TimeEnd should be copied based on the StartTime of the subsequent punch like the output with the original TimeEnd being the last Timeend

| Employee_Id | PunchXRefCode | TimeStart | TimeEnd |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001A | #DF_170304 | 10/23/2023 12:00:00 | 11/01/2023 12:00:00 |
| 001A | #DF_170304 | 10/28/2023 12:00:00 | 11/01/2023 12:00:00 |
| 001A | #DF_170304 | 10/31/2023 12:00:00 | 11/01/2023 12:00:00 |

I'm trying to output the dataset like below. I have the data sorted by Employee_id, PunchXRefCode, and TimeStart already.

| Employee_Id | PunchXRefCode | Id | TimeStart | TimeEnd |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001A | #DF_170304 | #DF_170304-1 | 10/23/2023 12:00:00 | 10/28/2023 12:00:00 |
| 001A | #DF_170304 | #DF_170304-2 | 10/28/2023 12:00:00 | 10/31/2023 12:00:00 |
| 001A | #DF_170304 | #DF_170304-3 | 10/31/2023 12:00:00 | 11/01/2023 12:00:00 |

Answer (score 0):

To create custom index and get the `TimeEnd` of subsequent row you should use window transformation in ADF.

Follow below steps:

- I took sample dataset as you provided in the question as below:
  [image]
- After this take a window Transformation with below settings:

As you have same `PunchXRefCode` code for all the rows we will group **over** that rows.
[image]
Then we will **sort** by `TimeStart` in ascending order
[image]
Then keep **Range by** Option as it is and create **Window Columns** with below expressions.

```json
TimeEnd : lead(TimeStart,1,TimeEnd)
Id : PunchXRefCode+' - '+toString(rowNumber())
```

[image]

**Output**

[image]